# Удаления (очистки) сообщений Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Можно ли к функционалу добавить (переделать) функцию удаления (очистки) предыдущих (полученных) сообщений от бота, чтобы эти сообщения (ответы) не накапливались (не засоряли чат).

Пример функционала

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main_menu(message):
.............
    elif message.text == KEYBOARD['FOR_A_DATAR']:
        msg = 'Для поиска ведите <b>фамилия </b> от 3 (трех) символов.'
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=kb, parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, select_last_name)


def select_last_name(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()   
    sql = "SELECT last_name, first_name, third_name, phone_v, phone_g, phone_m1, phone_m2 FROM dovidnyk WHERE last_name = ?"
    query = message.text
    query = query.title()
    cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    if not result:
        msg = 'Не нашол такую <b>{}</b> фамилию.'.format(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
        return
    else:
        for ln in result:
            msg =  "<i> <u>ФИО</u></i>:  <b>{} {} {}</b>\n" \
                   "<i> <u>Тел. внутр.</u></i>:  {}\n" \
                   "<i>☎️ <u>Тел. город.</u></i>:  {}\n" \
                   "<i> <u>Тел. моб. 1</u></i>:  {}\n" \
                   "<i> <u>Тел. моб. 2</u></i>:  {}\n".format(ln[0], ln[1], ln[2], ln[3], ln[4], ln[5], ln[6])
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### bot.delete_message(message.chat.id,message.message_id)

Полезная команда, которая позволяет удалять сообщение которым не больше чем 24
часа. Основной функционал удаление сообщений. В вашем случае пишите в начале
`bot.delete_message(message.chat.id,message.message_id - 1)` и это удалит **предыдущее**    сообщение. Способ применение очень прост, подробнее в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage)

Comment: я так пробовал он удаляет мое новое сообщение. Верху дополнил код

Comment: Ну тогда место -1 пишите -2

Comment: не работает даже если я поставлю -30, он удаляет мой запрос. а мне нужно чтобы он удалял ответы предыдущего запроса.

Comment: У участников в личной беседе бот не может удалять их сообщения.  Так как прав не хватает, также и вы не сможете удалять сообщения бота

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно удаление предыдущего сообщения,то можно воспользоваться :

```
bot.delete_message(chatid,messageid-1)
```

Если нужно удалить ВСЕ сообщения ,то можно попробовать записывать id сообщений ,отправляемых ботом и/или получаемых от пользователей,в массив/файл/БД. Чтобы удалять сообщения можно воспользоваться циклом:

```
bot = tb.TeleBot('TOKEN')  #ТОКЕН
with open(file,'r') as f:  #ЧТЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА И ЕГО ПРЕОБРАЗОВАНИЕ (Зависит от того,как 
    ids = f.read().splitlines() #записывать в файл)
for i in ids:               #ПОПЫТКА УДАЛИТЬ СООБЩЕНИЕ
    try:
        bot.delete_message(userid,i)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Сообщение не найдено! \n{e}')
```

У этого способа есть минус - он спамит запросами слишком быстро,поэтому иногда(если сообщений очень много) выкидывает ошибку и просит повторить запрос через n-ное кол-во времени. Добавление time.sleep(sec) существенно замедляет работу.

Источник : [api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage)